# Kendo DatePicker change event on Deleting

Tags: kendo-ui

Can someone tell me how to fire change event of kendo DatePicker element on deleting content using DELETE key or backspace. I need to update max date of another kendo DatePicker. second DatePicker doesn't get updated even I delete/clear date on the first kendo DatePicker

Answer (score 0):

I **do not** recommend you using it however you can trigger the change event manually like this:

```
$('#dPicker').data().kendoDatePicker.element.on('keydown',function(e){
      if(e.keyCode==8) //backspace
      {
           $(this).data().kendoDatePicker.trigger('change');
      }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker().bind("change", function(e) {
//handle change event here
}):
```

This will give you the change event

Answer (score 0):

```
$('some selector').bind('keyup', function (e) { $(this).data().kendoDatePicker._blur() })
```